# the background of TextView didnt change! Kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

im a newbie currently working on a health app school project.

i have found a problem when i was trying to change a TextView background with a drawable refrence. it like the color of the text view doesnt follow my line of program, but in some condition it runs perfectly.

the apparance of the app
[image: background textview didnt change]

the code
[image: the background code]

```
private fun updateIndikatorAu(){
        //Colors
        val colorHigh = "#e85218"
        val colorNormal = "#6b91ca"
        val colorLow = "#eeaf17"
        val colorNull = "#7F808B"

        //Fields
        indiAu = findViewById(R.id.textindi_au)
        kadarAu = findViewById(R.id.textkadarprof_au)
        satuanAu = findViewById(R.id.textsatuanprof_au)
        judulAu = findViewById(R.id.textprof_au)
        //Nilai
        val nilaiNullAU = 0
        val nilaiProfAU = kadarAu.text.toString()
        val nilai1AU = 7.0

        //converter Double
        val auNol = nilaiNullAU.toDouble()
        val auNormal1 = nilai1AU.toDouble()
        val auProf = nilaiProfAU.toDouble()

        //Nilai Tinggi
        if (auProf > auNormal1){
            indiAu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highbuttoncolor)
            satuanAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.highbuttoncolor)
            kadarAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorHigh))
            judulAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorHigh))
        }

        //Nilai Normal
        else if (auProf > auNol  && auProf < auNormal1){
            indiAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.normalbuttoncolor)
            satuanAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.normalbuttoncolor)
            kadarAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorNormal))
            judulAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorNormal))
        }

        //Nilai 0
        else if (auProf == auNol){
            indiAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.nullbuttoncolor)
            satuanAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.nullbuttoncolor)
            kadarAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorNull))
            judulAu.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorNull))
        }
    }
```

i have use the same method to change the background color before `setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorHigh))` like the text color change code.
it works fine but i need to maintain the rounded corner. so i use `R.drawable.highbuttoncolor` instead `android.graphics.color.parseColor(colorHigh)`. but the button color doesnt change perfectly.

please help me fix this problem, or explain me the condition why this problem can happen. i'll really grateful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey if you are using a `drawable` for setting the background you should use :

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable..)
```

But for just the color it would be:

```
setBackgroundColor(setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, R.color..)
```

From codewise i guess the first condition is working because you are using the correct one:

```
  indiAu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highbuttoncolor) // Correct
  satuanAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.highbuttoncolor) // You dont need this
```

but second and third condition you always only use:

```
 indiAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.normalbuttoncolor) // Wrong
 satuanAu.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.normalbuttoncolor) // You dont need this
```

So use there also `setBackgroundResource()`